# Session bean injection with CDI

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld

I am trying to inject a session bean into another session bean (in this particular case its the same session bean), and I get this error:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308
>   Unable to resolve any beans for Types: [interface
>   com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.ejb.stub.GeneralSession]; Bindings:
>   [@javax.enterprise.inject.New(value=com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.ejb.stub.GeneralSession.class)]

This is  how I am trying to do it:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@Local(GeneralSessionLocal.class)
@Remote(GeneralSession.class)
public class GeneralSessionBean extends CRUDSessionBase
{
    @Inject @New
    Instance<GeneralSession> generalSessionInstance;

    // ...
}
```

I get this error when I call `generalSessionInstance.get();`. Can anyone help?

Comment: You didn't specify in your question the programming language you were utilizing. However easy it is to guess, it's always good form to add tags with the appropriate programming language. Consider editing your question and doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying that the bean class (GeneralSessionBean) implements the GeneralSession.

In your case:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@Local(GeneralSessionLocal.class)
@Remote(GeneralSession.class)
public class GeneralSessionBean extends CRUDSessionBase implements GeneralSession
{
    @Inject @New
    Instance<GeneralSession> generalSessionInstance;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A remote interface is not a bean type, which is valid for injection, according to the WebBeans spec. So you have to take the local interface (in that case GeneralSessionLocal) for the field type (and you should also implement this interface, because otherwise it also isn't a bean type of your EJB).